# Adding touch/click event to a bitmap in android

Tags: android, input, events, touch

In my android game, there is a `surfaceview` which has 36 `bitmap`s drawn on it. I want to change the `bitmap`s when they are touched. Is there a way implement `touch` or `click` event to the `bitmap`s ?

Adding `touch` event to `surfaceview` and then to calculate the `bitmap` touched will be very tedious since there are 36 `bitmap`s.

Answer (score 1):

If i correctly understood you, then I believe, you can add a click listener to a bitmap just like to a jpg image or other format.

In my example the image_star is a png file.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some code
        }
    });
```

The xml :

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_star" 
    />
```

The result of this would be lower. The picture with a star in the middle is a clickable image, the `ImageView img` from my code. The upper button is an ImageButton.

[image]

Also there is a way to make it clickable only through the xml code, but im not sure how that is done, because i dont like that way.

Comment: Welcome to GD:SE, This is a very short answer and we generally try to provide as much concise information as needed to solve the question - can you add some example code to show it's implementation?

Comment: @Blue I have added some more to my answer!

Comment: This is much better! I encourage you to give more answers where you can and look into older, highly upvoted answers to see what to aim for!

Comment: hey i am drawing button bitmap, is it any way to set click method to them as i hadn't mentioned any imageView or button in my xml code

Answer (score 0):

a `Bitmap` itself cannot be clickable on Android. You have to draw each `Bitmap` to an `ImageView` or an `ImageButton`, and listen to that view's touch events.